# Proof: Newton-Raphsons numerical method is of second order

Tags: numerical-methods

In the proof of the fact that **Newton-Raphson** is a **second order numerical method** they use a **Taylor-sequence**.

Iterative formula for Newton-Raphson:

$x_n=x_{n-1} - \frac{F(x_{n-1})}{F'(x_{n-1})}$

**Why is there a factor $F''(\xi_{n-1})$ with $\xi_{n-1}$ between $\alpha$ and $x_{n-1}$ in the third term?**

[image]

Comment: If you work with a Taylor approximation, you should also work with some form of **error term.**

Comment: Ok, but how do you know the error term is in factor nr. 3? And Why isn’t there a term $F”(x_{n-1})$ in factor nr. 3?

Comment: This is the Lagrange remainder of a first order Taylor expansion.